# Silverlight and Wait that fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, task-parallel-library

I need to resolve via IoC a property that if not present must be taken on database.
all repository of mine are in the form

```
  Task<FilterResponse> GetFiltersForInquiries(int idIstituto);
```

but as the Wait/Result is called I got the UI frozen and no call to the webservice is made

my calling code is

```
   var container = new Container();

        container.RegisterSingle<IBodInquiryRepository>(new BodInquiryRepository());


        container.RegisterSingle<FilterResponse>(() =>
            {
                var repository = container.GetInstance<IBodInquiryRepository>();
                var res = repository.GetFiltersForInquiries(84).Result;

                return res;
            });
```

since I can't put an async/await what can I do?
if I were under WPF I would have done a sync call (it takes 6-7 seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Result` property and the `Wait()` method on a `Task` are blocking. When called from a UI thread this is a well known cause for deadlock because once the task is complete the continuation is attempted to be executed on the UI thread which is blocked so it cannot execute the continuation.

To avoid the problem, try changing your code to:

```
var res = await repository.GetFiltersForInquiries(84);
```

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by Stephen Cleary explains how you can avoid common pitfalls with `async/await`.

Alternatively you can try and call your `async` code prior to doing the container registrations.

```
var repository = container.GetInstance<IBodInquiryRepository>();
var res = await repository.GetFiltersForInquiries(84);
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterSingle<IBodInquiryRepository>(new BodInquiryRepository());


container.RegisterSingle<FilterResponse>(res);
```

Comment: I can't since I'm under a property registration...if I mark the lamda as async only GOD knows what it returns me the property resolution!

Comment: what about calling that code before the registration?

Comment: my goal of calling it at property resolution was to avoid that the user has to wait those seconds if he doesn't plan to use one of the functions that use those filters...btw maybe I can try making a methods that check if there are the filters and if not it register them..

Comment: that might be a good idea, IMO there is now way to avoid the wait for the `FilterResponse` to become available. You'll either block waiting for it or wait for it asynchronously